# How to add multiple labels for each row in tableLayoutPanel using window from c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

How to add multiple labels,radio button,checklistboxes for each row in tableLayoutPanel using window from c#

Comment: You didn't tray anything yet? Too lazy?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

try like this: Its a Sample for adding controls in tablelayoutpanel

```
tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 100))
tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 100))
tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 100))
CType(xPage.Controls(0), TableLayoutPanel).ColumnCount =3

TableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 80.0F))
TableLayoutPanel.RowCount +=1

 TableLayoutPanel).Controls.Add(label1, 0, 0)
 TableLayoutPanel).Controls.Add(radiobutton, 1, 0)
 TableLayoutPanel).Controls.Add(checkbox,2, 0)
```